# change fluid image aspect ration css

Tags: css, image, fluid-layout, scaletransform

I'm trying to place 6 images one next to another with css,
the whole thing should be able to scale pretty well in most displays (except for mobile for the moment)
so I've made this:
http://pelloponisos.telesto.gr/galleryTest/test/gallery.php#
(apparently I'm trying to make yet another carousel)

most of my images have a bigger width than height so when I scaled them I just put 
width:x% in the li container and 100% for the image width.

but the sixth image is different and it causes quite a bit of trouble
I tried setting the height too but you can only scale the images based on one of the two.

The only thing that worked so far was to put a static height in the ul and then scale in both width and height but then it's not  a fluid grid.

is there any way to make all li elements have a fluid height and then scale all images based on that? or if not
is there any way to make any image with different ratio scale to the one I specify in the css?

Answer (score 1):

I stripped down your code a little bit, but this seems to get closer to the idea. The trick is to set the width in the container (.upper ul li) then for the images use: max-width:100%; height:auto. Also, the padding is now in %.

```
            #carousel{
            position:relative;
            }
            #wrapper{
            margin:0 auto;
            }

            #slides{
            width: 100%;
            }
            .upper ul li{
            width: 200px;
            max-width: 100%;
            list-style:none outside none;
            float:left;
            padding-bottom:5px;
            padding:2%; 
            }
            img.galleryThumbnail{
            max-width:100%;
            height:auto;
            }
            .info{
            display:none;
            }

            #buttons img{
            position:absolute;
            top:90px;
            }
            #buttons #prev img{
            position:absolute;
            left:29px;}
            #buttons #next img{
            position:absolute;
            right:21px;
            }
```

Comment: hmm, the max-width is too large for what I want.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work,
also tried max-height:120px and removed the width from the li's but also didn't work

thanks for the answer, hadn't thought of it :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip :D, I was wondering wether it could be done without setting a static width anywhere (and everything getting its size from the window width )